# Specifying the same CSS class to multiple tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This seems pretty simple but I am not able to find a solution yet. If I want to apply a bootstrap class to all children (of a particular type e.g `<td>` below) of a tag, is there a way to do that without specifying it separately for each child tag? I have searched through other SO Posts but many of them talk about applying the same style to all child elements with CSS but I don't want to apply the effective style directly in the CSS because that will be redundant (since there already exists pre-defined class that I'd like to apply to all child tags, ideally).

For example:

If I need `<td class="text-right">` for every cell in the first column, I have to do:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr><td class="text-right" valign="middle">..</tr>
  <tr><td class="text-right" valign="middle">..</tr>
  <tr><td class="text-right" valign="middle">..</tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to do it in a more modular fashion? I know that we cant reference a CSS class inside another, else the above would be simple to do.

Comment: is it what you need?: `.table tr > td:first-child {text-align: right;}`

Comment: No, as I mentioned, I don't want to apply the effective styling directly. I am trying to find out if there's a way to apply a class to all children of an element (without repeating it in every child element). The above is just an example. I also have <span class="label label-default">Some text</span> in every cell in the first column and face the same issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you exactly need to apply class (not just CSS style) you should use JS. Something like this (jquery):

```
$('table tr td:first-child').addClass('text-right').attr('valign','middle');
```

Comment: Ah ok. Is JS the only way to do it then? I am using React and can try to add the class through that then.

I am doing this mostly for code modularity and maintainability.

Comment: The "class" property is the DOM element property. You can't access them from CSS, but from JS you can. Use React, it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is apply alignment styling - you don't need a class for that - you can do it with CSS - note that I added an aqua background to highlight the effect (its hard to see alignment in this smalle sample table).

EDIT - I have amened my answer to suit OP's situation - iterating over each of the tr's in the .table and then finding the first td within that and applying the addClass().

})

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.table tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td:first').addClass('text-right');
  })
})
```

```css
.table tr td{
  width:100px
  
}

.text-right{
  text-align:right;
  background:aqua
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle">test 1</td>
    <td valign="middle">test 2</td>
    <td valign="middle">test 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle">test 1</td>
    <td valign="middle">test 2</td>
    <td valign="middle">test 3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="middle">test 1</td>
    <td valign="middle">test 2</td>
    <td valign="middle">test 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hi - updated my answer to suit - iterate over each tr and find the first td - and add the class. I swapped the background to aqua to highlight.